how to process redshift connector in lambda function
This is the lambda function I use this inside a stepfunction and try to load the csv file to redshift table it requires layers , I too tried to install via pip still im getting the below error
import redshift_connector 
import pandas as pd
import boto3
import sys


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    # Initialize Redshift Connector
    host ='REDSHIFT ARN'
    port = ******
    database = '*********'
    user = '*******'
    password = '*******'
    
    # Initialize Redshift Connector
    conn = redshift_connector.connect(
        host=host,
        port=port,
        database=database,
        user=user,
        password=password
    )
    print(f"connection success {host}")
    
    # Access the values of the arguments
    bucket_name = event['validation_result']['Payload']['bucket_name']
    print(bucket_name)
    source_folder = event['validation_result']['Payload']['folder_name']
    file_name = event['validation_result']['Payload']['file_name']
    result={}
    result['bucket_name']=bucket_name
    result['file_name']=file_name

    # Load CSV file into a Pandas DataFrame
    csv_file_path = f's3://{bucket_name}/{source_folder}/{file_name}'
    print(csv_file_path)
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path)

    
    # Define the Redshift table name
    table_name = 'club_games'  # Change this to your actual Redshift table name
    
        # Insert data into the Redshift table
    for _, row in df[columns].iterrows():
        values = ', '.join([f"'{value}'" if isinstance(value, str) else str(value) for value in row])
        insert_sql = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} VALUES ({values})"
        cursor.execute(insert_sql)
        conn.commit()
    
    # Archive the processed CSV file
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')

    archive_key='archive' + '/' + file_name 
    object_key= folder_name + '/' + file_name
    # Copy the file to the archive folder
    s3.copy_object(Bucket=bucket_name, CopySource={'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': object_key}, Key=archive_key)
    
    # Delete the original file from the input folder
    s3.delete_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=object_key)
    
    conn.commit()
    # Close the Redshift connection
    conn.close()
    return result


However I tried installing the pip libraries for redshift_connector still it showing is there another way to solve this
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'redshift_connector'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "c0aa62a9-e77d-44d3-b92b-acb9e7362ebd",
  "stackTrace": []
}```


we need more detail about how you prepared the lambda layer, the handler code doesn't matter much in this case


mkdir -p my-lambda-layer/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages
pip install redshift_connector -t my-lambda-layer/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/
cd my-lambda-layer
zip -r ../my-lambda-layer.zip .
cd ..
6.Go to the AWS Lambda console
Navigate to "Layers" and create a new layer.
Upload the my-lambda-layer.zip
This is the way I uploaded my lambda layer when I tried uploading my redshift_connector y logs throw the error of no module named 'pandas' , when I tried to merge both and upload it , it will throw the error of missing fsspec ...Couldn't escape this maze @Anentropic


Please don't add comments to clarify, code is hard to read in comments and they are usually shown by number of votes, not chronologically. [Edit] your question instead, and put everything in one place.

@user22331353 read the docs for lambda layers - your lambda code and the contents of site-packages sub dir should be at the root of the layer zip, you don't want all the other directory tree structure

I have always used the psycopg2 library for connecting to Redshift from Python Lambda functions.  Code example below.
import psycopg2
...
dbconn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='%s' port='%s' user='%s' host='%s' 
password='%s'" % (dbname, dbport, dbuser, dbhost, dbpass))


I also tried to use psycopg2 by creating an layer through pip installer again my lambda layer throws no model named psycopg2
